# Using the *Messages* buffer

Tags: buffers

When making new elisp packages, would one customarily write to the `*Messages*` buffer or to a package dedicated buffer?  Particularly putting in consideration that the `*Messages*` has been described as a read-only buffer.  What is its use exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of any reason to write to the `*Messages*` buffer, unless the purpose of your package is to change the interface of the `*Messages*` buffer. There are only very rare circumstances where it's appropriate to read from `*Messages*` (occasionally it's a last resort to obtain some information that Emacs or some package doesn't make available in a more convenient way, but that's a last resort).

The role of [`*Messages*`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Logging-Messages.html) is to keep a history of messages that Emacs (or some package) has written to the [echo area](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/The-Echo-Area.html). The normal way to cause something to appear in `*Messages*` is with the [`message` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Displaying-Messages.html#index-message).

You should call `message` when there is something useful to report to the user. For example, if an error causes an interactive command to abort, Emacs prints a description of the error to the echo area (this is built into Emacs, but equivalent to calling `message`). `count-words-region` prints the counts. `what-cursor-position` prints the cursor position. Choosing to replace all occurrences in `query-replace` prints the number of replacements. Some commands that might occasionally take a long time print a message before they start the potentially blocking action (e.g. auto-save in case it stalls when saving to a network drive). Some (but not all) commands that enter an unusual form of interaction (where characters don't just insert themselves) print short usage instructions. Etc.